# api youtube in swift 3 error 403

Tags: swift3, ios10

I am trying to use youtube api in ios swift, and following this tutorial 
http://www.appcoda.com/youtube-api-ios-tutorial/
HTTP Status Code = 403
Error while loading channel details: nil

I'm using swift 3

```
var urlString = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=\(textField.text)&type=\(type)&key=\(apiKey)"
urlString = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!

// Create a NSURL object based on the above string.
let targetURL = URL(string: urlString)

// Get the results.
performGetRequest(targetURL, completion: { (data, HTTPStatusCode, error) -> Void in
    if HTTPStatusCode == 200 && error == nil {
        // Convert the JSON data to a dictionary object.
        do {
            let resultsDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

            // Get all search result items ("items" array).
            let items: Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>> = resultsDict["items"] as! Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>

            // Loop through all search results and keep just the necessary data.
            for i in 0 ..< items.count {
                let snippetDict = items[i]["snippet"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

                // Gather the proper data depending on whether we're searching for channels or for videos.
                if self.segDisplayedContent.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
                    // Keep the channel ID.
                    self.desiredChannelsArray.append(snippetDict["channelId"] as! String)
                }
                else {
                    // Create a new dictionary to store the video details.
                    var videoDetailsDict = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
                    videoDetailsDict["title"] = snippetDict["title"]
                    videoDetailsDict["thumbnail"] = ((snippetDict["thumbnails"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["default"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["url"]
                    videoDetailsDict["videoID"] = (items[i]["id"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["videoId"]

                    // Append the desiredPlaylistItemDataDict dictionary to the videos array.
                    self.videosArray.append(videoDetailsDict)

                    // Reload the tableview.
                    self.tblVideos.reloadData()
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        // Call the getChannelDetails(…) function to fetch the channels.
        if self.segDisplayedContent.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            self.getChannelDetails(true)
        }

    }
    else {
        print("HTTP Status Code = \(HTTPStatusCode)")
        print("Error while loading channel videos: \(error)")
    }

    // Hide the activity indicator.
    self.viewWait.isHidden = true
})


return true
```

}

```
// MARK: Custom method implementation

func performGetRequest(_ targetURL: URL!, completion: @escaping (_ data: Data?, _ HTTPStatusCode: Int, _ error: NSError?) -> Void) {
   // let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: targetURL)
   // request.httpMethod = "GET"

    var request = URLRequest(url: targetURL)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration)

  /*  let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            completion(data, (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode, error)
        })
    } as! (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)*/


  /*  let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: ({ (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            completion(data as Data?, (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode, error)
        })
        } as! (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void))*/
  let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(data, (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode, error as? NSError) } }

    task.resume()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

- First of all the JSON dictionary representation in Swift 3 is `[String:Any]` (aka `Dictionary<String,Any>`)
- Second of all in Swift 3 all parameter labels in closures have been removed

  ```
  func performGetRequest(_ targetURL: URL, completion: @escaping (Data?, Int, NSError?) -> Void) {
  ```

  Do not use implicit unwrapped optionals for method parameter types. Either use regular optional (`?`) or non-optional.

Answer (score 0):

Error 403 means Forbidden Access. Make sure you have the **correct** **apiKey** from google/youtube developer.

I also used the appcoda youtube api tutorial (which is in Swift 2 I think) and this is a working version of mine for swift 3.

```
    func getVideosForChannelAtIndex() {


    let urlString = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=\(playlistID)&maxResults=\(maxResults)&key=\(apiKey)"

    // Create a NSURL object based on the above string.
    let targetURL = URL(string: urlString)

    // Fetch the playlist from Google.
    performGetRequest(targetURL!) { (data, HTTPStatusCode, error) -> Void in



        if HTTPStatusCode == 200 && error == nil {
            do {
                self.videos = []

                // Convert the JSON data into a dictionary.
                let resultsDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>

                // Get all playlist items ("items" array).
                let items:Array<Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>> = resultsDict["items"] as! Array<Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>>

                // Use a loop to go through all video items.
                //                    for var i=0; i<items.count; ++i
                for i in 0 ..< items.count {
                    let playlistSnippetDict = (items[i] as Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>)["snippet"] as! Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>

                    let video = Video()
                    video.title = playlistSnippetDict["title"] as? String
                    //                        video.thumbnail =
                    video.videoId = (playlistSnippetDict["resourceId"] as? Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>)?["videoId"] as? String

                    guard let thumbnail = ((playlistSnippetDict["thumbnails"] as? Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>)?["high"] as? Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>)?["url"] as? String else {
                        video.thumbnail = UIImage(named: "Icon1024x1024")
                        return
                    }

                    guard let url:URL? = URL(string: thumbnail), let data:Data? = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) else {
                        video.thumbnail = UIImage(named: "Icon1024x1024")
                        return
                    }

                    if let dataImage = data {
                        video.thumbnail = UIImage(data: dataImage)
                    } else {
                        video.thumbnail = UIImage(named: "Icon1024x1024")
                    }

                    self.videos.append(video)

                    // Reload the tableview.
                    self.tblVideos.reloadData()
                }
            } catch {
                print("json error: \(error)")
            }
        } else {
            print("")
            print("HTTP Status Code = \(HTTPStatusCode)")
            print("")

            //Show alertDialog here with Error
            print("Error while loading videos: \(error?.localizedDescription)")

            let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Oops!", message: error?.localizedDescription, delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            alert.show()

        }

        // Hide the activity indicator.
        self.viewWait.isHidden =  true
    }

}
```

This is for the performGetRequest

```
func performGetRequest(_ targetURL: URL, completion: @escaping (_ data: Data?, _ HTTPStatusCode: Int?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {

    var request = URLRequest(url: targetURL)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            completion(data, (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode, error)
        })

    }

    task.resume()
}
```